# Glassfish @PersistenceContext

Tags: jpa, glassfish, eclipselink

I have the ollowing persistence.xml in my JSF project using eclipse:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="EnglishOnline" transaction-type="JTA">
        <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
        <class>org.englishonline.persistence.User</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="create-tables" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/englishonline" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="porcelainbus" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

At the same time I have the following Backing bean:

```
import java.util.Date;

import org.englishonline.persistence.*;
import javax.faces.bean.*;
import javax.persistence.*;

@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class Login {    

    @PersistenceContext(unitName="EnglishOnline")
    private EntityManager em;
    private String login = null;
    private String password = null;

    public String getLogin() {
        return login;
    }
    public void setLogin(String login) {
        this.login = login;
    }
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }
    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String performLogin() {
        if (login.equals(password)) {

            EntityTransaction tx = em.getTransaction();
            User user = new User();
            user.setBirthdate(new Date());
            user.setLogin(login);
            user.setPassword(password);
            user.setName("Bobby");
            user.setRegistrationdate(new Date());
            user.setSex(Sex.MALE);
            tx.begin();
            em.persist(user);
            tx.commit();

            return null;            
        } else {
            return null;
        }

    }

}
```

But when I try to submit the button in my app, the server log gives this:

```
  WARNING: RAR5117 : Failed to obtain/create connection from connection pool [ DerbyPool ]. Reason : com.sun.appserv.connectors.internal.api.PoolingException: Connection could not be allocated because: java.net.ConnectException : Connection to localhost port 1527  Connection refused: connect.
    WARNING: RAR5114 : Error allocating connection : [Error in allocating a connection. Cause: Connection could not be allocated because: java.net.ConnectException : Connection refused: connect.]
    SEVERE: Local Exception Stack: 
    Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.3.0.v20110604-r9504): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
    Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLException: Error in allocating a connection. Cause: Connection could not be allocated because: java.net.ConnectException : Connection refused: connect.
    Error Code: 0
        at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException.sqlException(DatabaseException.java:309)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.JNDIConnector.connect(JNDIConnector.java:135)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.DatasourceLogin.connectToDatasource(DatasourceLogin.java:162)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.DatabaseSessionImpl.loginAndDetectDatasource(DatabaseSessionImpl.java:582)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryProvider.login(EntityManagerFactoryProvider.java:206)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.deploy(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:472)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.getDatabaseSession(EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.java:188)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.createEntityManagerImpl(EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.java:277)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManagerImpl(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:290)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:275)
        at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.EntityManagerWrapper._getDelegate(EntityManagerWrapper.java:218)
        at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.EntityManagerWrapper.getTransaction(EntityManagerWrapper.java:857)
        at org.englishonline.backing.Login.performLogin(Login.java:34)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:234)
        at com.sun.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:297)
        at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
        at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:88)
        at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
        at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)
        at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:794)
        at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1259)
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
        at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:593)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1539)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:281)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:98)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.invoke(PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.java:91)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:162)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:330)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:231)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:174)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:828)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:725)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1019)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:225)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
        at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
        at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
        at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
        at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
        at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
    Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Error in allocating a connection. Cause: Connection could not be allocated because: java.net.ConnectException : Ошибка соединения с сервером localhost на порту 1527 с сообщением Connection refused: connect.
        at com.sun.gjc.spi.base.DataSource.getConnection(DataSource.java:151)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.JNDIConnector.connect(JNDIConnector.java:132)
        ... 52 more
    Caused by: javax.resource.spi.ResourceAllocationException: Error in allocating a connection. Cause: Connection could not be allocated because: java.net.ConnectException : Ошибка соединения с сервером localhost на порту 1527 с сообщением Connection refused: connect.
        at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.ConnectionManagerImpl.internalGetConnection(ConnectionManagerImpl.java:307)
        at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.ConnectionManagerImpl.allocateConnection(ConnectionManagerImpl.java:190)
        at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.ConnectionManagerImpl.allocateConnection(ConnectionManagerImpl.java:165)
        at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.ConnectionManagerImpl.allocateConnection(ConnectionManagerImpl.java:160)
        at com.sun.gjc.spi.base.DataSource.getConnection(DataSource.java:145)
        ... 53 more
```

And the JPA provider does nothing.

Comment: Your error reminds me of.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10420902/data-sources-derby-connection-refused

Comment: As for your example - port 1527 is the native port for Derby. + my server is definetely running and the database too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You specified the transaction-type as JTA which requires a JTA datasource.  You will want to use "resource_local" if you wish to specify the jdbc.url and control the transactions directly instead of using JTA.