# Derby classpath can't connect to database

Tags: sql, database, jdbc, derby

I just installed derby and I followed the instructions from [here](http://db.apache.org/derby/papers/DerbyTut/install_software.html) the exact same way it told me to but replacing the paths with my paths. But for some reason why i try to create a connection to connect to create a Database and run my sql scripts to create the tables and populate them it gives me a few errors firstly is this one

```
ERROR 08001: No suitable driver found for jdbc:derby:SuperMarket;create=true
```

Then when my sql scripts run I get this error

```
IJ ERROR: Unable to establish connection
```

I dont see what I did wrong this is the line i used to set the class path

```
C:\> set CLASSPATH=%DERBY_INSTALL%\lib\derby.jar;%DERBY_INSTALL%\lib\derbytools.jar;.
```

I included the derby.jar file that was needed so I can't see the problem does anyone know what I did wrong? Also when I run

```
 connect 'jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/MyDB';
```

The server starts fine

```
C:\Derbs\db-derby-10.10.2.0-bin\bin>startNetworkServer
Thu Jun 26 11:56:38 PDT 2014 : Security manager installed using the Basic server
 security policy.
Thu Jun 26 11:56:39 PDT 2014 : Apache Derby Network Server - 10.10.2.0 - (158244
6) started and ready to accept connections on port 1527
```

Answer (score 2):

There are many troubles when I start using DerbyDB. It is really painful to practice.

**1.** **For example,** I download Derby from http://db.apache.org/derby/derby_downloads.html#Latest+Official+Releases

**2.** Unzip to `C:\tools\db-derby-10.11.1.1-bin`.
[image]

**3.** Press Windows key + <kbd>R</kbd>, type: `SystemPropertiesAdvanced`, set up environment variables.
[image]

Reference: https://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.0/manuals/getstart/gspr16.html

**4.** Run `cmd`, 
We should run additional command:

```
C:\tools\db-derby-10.11.1.1-bin\bin\NetworkServerControl.bat
```

and type:

```
C:\tools\db-derby-10.11.1.1-bin\bin\ij.bat
```

then press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, and result:
[image]

**5.** We will put in-memory Derby database to `D:\` directory. Folder `vy1` **must doesn't exit**. We type command for creating new database named `vy1`:

```
connect 'jdbc:derby:D:\vy1;create=true';
```

Use Windows Explorer, go to directory `D:\vy1`, you will see new folder named `vy1` just created.

then type command:

```
connect 'D:\vy1'
```

**6.** See SQL command to create database, table, insert, then read database like this:

[image]

(Open images in new web page is better for view. Note: This is my old screenshot when I use older version few months ago).

**Come back to your question,** focus at section 3, and commnand call `NetworkServerControl.bat` at section 4.

Good luck! :)