# Derby client jdbc driver connection error : Failed to create database 'sample'

Tags: java, jdbc, connection, client-server, derby

I started the Derby Network Server like stated in this tutorial - [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10420902/data-sources-derby-connection-refused/12176840#12176840).

But when i typed:

```
ij>  connect 'jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/sample;create=true',
```

I get the following error:

> ERROR XJ041: DERBY SQL error: ERRORCODE: 40000, SQLSTATE: XJ041,
>   SQLERRMC: Faile d to create database 'sample', see the next exception
>   for details.::SQLSTATE: XB M0H

Any ideas how to fix this ?

`derby.log` contents:

```
Tue Oct 13 10:56:03 EEST 2015 : Apache Derby Network Server - 10.11.1.2 - (1629631) started and ready to accept connections on port 1527
Tue Oct 13 10:56:10 EEST 2015 Thread[DRDAConnThread_2,5,main] Cleanup action starting
ERROR XBM0H: Directory C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\db\bin\sample cannot be created.
at org.apache.derby.iapi.error.StandardException.newException(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.iapi.error.StandardException.newException(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.StorageFactoryService$10.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.StorageFactoryService.createServiceRoot(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.bootService(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.createPersistentService(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.FileMonitor.createPersistentService(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.iapi.services.monitor.Monitor.createPersistentService(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection.createDatabase(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection.<init>(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.jdbc.InternalDriver.getNewEmbedConnection(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.jdbc.InternalDriver.connect(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.jdbc.InternalDriver.connect(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver.connect(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.drda.Database.makeConnection(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.drda.DRDAConnThread.getConnFromDatabaseName(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.drda.DRDAConnThread.verifyUserIdPassword(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.drda.DRDAConnThread.parseSECCHK(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.drda.DRDAConnThread.parseDRDAConnection(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.drda.DRDAConnThread.processCommands(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.drda.DRDAConnThread.run(Unknown Source)
Cleanup action completed
Tue Oct 13 10:56:10 EEST 2015 Thread[DRDAConnThread_2,5,main] Cleanup action starting
java.sql.SQLException: Failed to create database 'sample', see the next exception for details.
at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.Util.seeNextException(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection.createDatabase(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection.<init>(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.jdbc.InternalDriver.getNewEmbedConnection(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.jdbc.InternalDriver.connect(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.jdbc.InternalDriver.connect(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver.connect(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.drda.Database.makeConnection(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.drda.DRDAConnThread.getConnFromDatabaseName(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.drda.DRDAConnThread.verifyUserIdPassword(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.drda.DRDAConnThread.parseSECCHK(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.drda.DRDAConnThread.parseDRDAConnection(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.drda.DRDAConnThread.processCommands(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.drda.DRDAConnThread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: ERROR XJ041: Failed to create database 'sample', see the next exception for details.
at org.apache.derby.iapi.error.StandardException.newException(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory.wrapArgsForTransportAcrossDRDA(Unknown Source)
... 16 more
Caused by: ERROR XBM0H: Directory C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\db\bin\sample cannot be created.
at org.apache.derby.iapi.error.StandardException.newException(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.iapi.error.StandardException.newException(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.StorageFactoryService$10.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.StorageFactoryService.createServiceRoot(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.bootService(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.createPersistentService(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.FileMonitor.createPersistentService(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.iapi.services.monitor.Monitor.createPersistentService(Unknown Source)
... 13 more
============= begin nested exception, level (1) ===========
java.sql.SQLException: Directory C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\db\bin\sample cannot be created.
at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.Util.generateCsSQLException(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.TransactionResourceImpl.wrapInSQLException(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.TransactionResourceImpl.handleException(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection.handleException(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection.createDatabase(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection.<init>(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.jdbc.InternalDriver.getNewEmbedConnection(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.jdbc.InternalDriver.connect(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.jdbc.InternalDriver.connect(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver.connect(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.drda.Database.makeConnection(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.drda.DRDAConnThread.getConnFromDatabaseName(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.drda.DRDAConnThread.verifyUserIdPassword(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.drda.DRDAConnThread.parseSECCHK(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.drda.DRDAConnThread.parseDRDAConnection(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.drda.DRDAConnThread.processCommands(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.drda.DRDAConnThread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: ERROR XBM0H: Directory C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\db\bin\sample cannot be created.
at org.apache.derby.iapi.error.StandardException.newException(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.iapi.error.StandardException.newException(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.StorageFactoryService$10.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.StorageFactoryService.createServiceRoot(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.bootService(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.createPersistentService(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.FileMonitor.createPersistentService(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.iapi.services.monitor.Monitor.createPersistentService(Unknown Source)
... 13 more
============= end nested exception, level (1) ===========
============= begin nested exception, level (2) ===========
ERROR XBM0H: Directory C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\db\bin\sample cannot be created.
at org.apache.derby.iapi.error.StandardException.newException(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.iapi.error.StandardException.newException(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.StorageFactoryService$10.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.StorageFactoryService.createServiceRoot(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.bootService(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.createPersistentService(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.FileMonitor.createPersistentService(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.iapi.services.monitor.Monitor.createPersistentService(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection.createDatabase(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection.<init>(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.jdbc.InternalDriver.getNewEmbedConnection(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.jdbc.InternalDriver.connect(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.jdbc.InternalDriver.connect(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver.connect(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.drda.Database.makeConnection(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.drda.DRDAConnThread.getConnFromDatabaseName(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.drda.DRDAConnThread.verifyUserIdPassword(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.drda.DRDAConnThread.parseSECCHK(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.drda.DRDAConnThread.parseDRDAConnection(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.drda.DRDAConnThread.processCommands(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.drda.DRDAConnThread.run(Unknown Source)
============= end nested exception, level (2) ===========
Cleanup action completed
Tue Oct 13 10:56:10 EEST 2015 Thread[DRDAConnThread_2,5,main] (DATABASE = sample), (DRDAID = {1}), Failed to create database 'sample', see the next exception for details.
Tue Oct 13 10:56:10 EEST 2015 Thread[DRDAConnThread_2,5,main] (DATABASE = sample), (DRDAID = {1}), Directory C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\db\bin\sample cannot be created.
```

Comment: Can you find your 'derby.log' file that your Derby Network Server has created? Look in that log and you will find the full exception that the Derby Network Server encountered when it tried to create your database. Copy that log output into your question here.

Comment: I've observed the same problem. Another observation is that the database was first created on a Mac device, then viewed on a Windows device which showed the above error message. The database version is not compatible with the driver.

Comment: In fact, I fixed the above problem by installing Derby 10.14 version.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The log entry states:

> Directory C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\db\bin\sample cannot be created

So as far as I know this could be some permission issue with `network server` process not having enough rights to create a directory in `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\db\bin\`. You can try to run it as administrator.

Answer (score 1):

From your exception stack trace it looks like your Derby network server process was started in the folder `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\db\bin\` and the process does not seem to have the privileges to write the (Derby database) files in that folder. Try to find a folder where the Derby server process has the privilege to write files into. You can give specify windows drive letters and paths in the Derby connect URL. Just make sure to convert any back slashes `\` to forward slashes `/` or escape them like this `\\`. So if for example if you know the Derby server process can write to d:\temp folder, then you can compose your command as

`ij>  connect jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/d:/temp/sample;create=true`

or

`ij>  connect jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/d:\\temp\\sample;create=true`

Answer (score 0):

Beware substituted drives when using Derby - if you put your database on a substituted drive it won't work and you get confusing nio exceptions and class cast errors in the log.  So this does **not** work:

```
connect 'jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/t:/DerbyDB;create=true';
```

where t is substituted.  The same command pointed at drive c does work:

```
connect 'jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/c:/DerbyDB;create=true';
```

There is a discussion of these issues on the Derby site, -  but maybe its not fixed for all cases? including where the database itself is on a substituted drive.  I'm currently using version 10.10.2.0